# Generic return type in object transformation

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts an object and returns a new one with additional properties. And I cannot figure out why this generic typing doesn't work.

```
const obj = { name: 'hello', id: 1 };

const transformObj = <T extends { name: string }>({ name, ...rest }: T): T & { newName: string } => ({
    name,
    newName: name + '1',
    ...rest,
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGYCGBbApgFwwDkAFvgDaUgkA0MAlgCbECMMAvgNwBQvoSLCgAnbJABmIEbgDySVDAA8AFRj4AHlHxhmEDFjxEY0EYzABzLgD4AFJhwEGAOlcj80LsRUBKbzAAyAzB8AHcAOSNiU3MrTlRrGHteGFTDJxS0kIio9PwYAGpSNnpM1Ndnd2g6Xk4fbiA)

It returns this error

```
Type '{ name: string; newName: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "name">>' is not assignable to type 'T & { newName: string; }'. Type '{ name: string; newName: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "name">>' is not assignable to type 'T'. '{ name: string; newName: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "name">>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ name: string; }'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why it doesn't work as written. Notice the `{ newName: number }` in `obj`. This object does meet the constraint `<T extends { name: string }>`, but trying to intersect it with `{ newName: string }` creates a contradiction.

```js
const obj = { name: 'hello', /**/ newName: 10 /**/, id: 1 };
```

This gives you the type you want, by removing `"newName"` from `keyof rest` with destructuring and then adding it back as a `string`.

```js
const transformObj = <T extends { name: string, newName?: unknown }>({ name, newName, ...rest }: T): typeof rest & { name: string, newName: string } => ({
    ...rest,    
    name,
    newName: name + '1',
});
```

Comment: Interesting. But if `newName` is the problem, why does it also happen with [this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGYCGBbApgFwwDkAFvgDaUgkA0MAlgCbECMMAvgNwBQvoSLCgAnbJABmIEbgDySVDAA8AFRj4AHlHxhmEDFjxEY0EYzABzLgD4AFJhwEGAOlcj80LsRUBKb6msYe14YUMMnELDXZ3doOl5OH24gA)? (And amusingly, I did try an approach with `newName` in the generic constraint, but I made it `newName: never`. Your `newName?: unknown` makes much more sense.)

Comment: I think that's just a limitation of the compiler; it can't tell that `{ name: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "name">>` is equivalent to T given `<T extends { name: string }>`.

Comment: Hmm, your simplification does seem to compile but it's [incorrect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGYCGBbApgFwwDkAFvgDaUgkA0W+A7gHJ5EwCMADAwJYATYpxgBfANwAoSaEiwoAJ2yQAZiAW4A8klQwAPABUY+AB5R8YARAxZ2xaAr5gA5mIB8ACkw4CDAHQBCvjQYsQGAJTEUACeAA74ICowQSEAZDY+HA5OzgxgzGwE9oo5YqhuMF6SMDW2vtW1+ax2dfgwANSknPQNNQF+KVB0kqLhUjLgECCU+H40zh6KyhBqGtqIHgiI4WMwAPR7NgBEmUfERxTUIEcMJwXsZ1y8MEeCjyKiMEA)-- you need to put `newName` after `...rest`.

Comment: No, that seems fine, I ran it with `ctrl+enter` and got `{ "newName": "hello1", "id": 1, "name": "hello" } `.

Comment: @JoshWilson - The example wasnt clear. The problem is the type of the result: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvGYCGBbApgFwwDkAFvgDaUgkA0W+A7gHJ5EwCMADAwJYATYpxgBfANwAoSaEiwoAJ2yQAZiAW4A8klQwAPABUY+AB5R8YARAxZ2xaAr5gA5mIB8ACkw4CDAHQBCvjQYsQGAJTEUACeAA74ICowQSEAZDY+HA5OzgxgzGwE9oo5YqhuMF6SMDUwAX4pUHTVtZnNtYysdrYEMADUpJz0kqLhUjLgISkArpSwaIrKEGoa2ogeCIhjMAD0OzYARJkHxAcU1CAHDEcF7CdcvDAHgvciojCSM3N++V0E4rt9jF4jA+NZ8gA3fAKBjwfDAbDTCD4UGwBFgEiwOEweAgKBkLDTXBwhQwZQCGDZFxk+QUSnsGBQPgEIA Notice that `result.newName` is of type `never`. But the code in your answer...

Comment: ...doesn't have that problem. `newName` is `string` as intended. :-) Which I think means it does need to be there in the constraint after all. Need to play more, but in any case, thank you for `typeof rest`! (And for posting this answer.) Very useful...

Comment: Just FYI, the return type annotation is unnecessary in this case. TypeScript will infer it exactly the same.